# C++ code using stack

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that is a simple expression checker. All the program is to do is to check if a given input by the user is well-formed or not. I have three files I am woring with. I will post portions of each below. My question is in the main.cpp under case one if I have it coded right. I'm new to stacks and am not sure if I coded it correctly on what I want to happen. Just in case the code is to get an expression followed by a : and if the input is `'('` then push on to stack and if answer is `)'` then get top and compare to see if they are pairs. Then output if the expression is well-formed or not. Thanks.

Here is  the code:

main.cpp

```
switch (choice){
case 1: 
    cout << "Current Setting: () " << endl;
    cout << "Enter your expression followed by a ; : " << endl;
    do {

    cin >> answer;


    if (answer = '(')
        stack.push( '(' );
    else 
        if (answer = ')' )
        (stack.top() == '(')




            while (answer != ';');
```

Stack.h

```
elemType top(void) const;
// precondition: this stack is not empty
// returns top element in this stack

// transformers
void push(const elemType& item);
// precondition: this stack is not full
// adds item to this stack

void pop(void);
// removes top element from this stack if exist
// remains empty otherwise
```

Comment: Try running the code and see if you got the answer.

Comment: Could this be homework? Perhaps adding the HOMEWORK tag would be appropriate?

Comment: what are you doing `(stack.top() == '(')` for, it is an `==` that doesn't get used by your program in any way (from what I can tell), maybe explain the problem a little better.

Comment: its unclear what you really want to do. give additional details

Comment: I did give the details of what I was trying to do in above in my post

Comment: You might want to review the difference between `=` and `==`. Also, there is an STL stack you can use if you are allowed.

Comment: What's the question... ?

Answer (score 0):

NO.
You are reading whole expression where as you are trying to compare it with one character.

```
if (answer = '(')
```

Also the loop is doing nothing

```
 while (answer != ';');
```

Comment: This a is portion of the code. I have the  `do {` at the top of the code for the `while` loop

Comment: You'll still need a closing brace before the `while`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
if (answer = '(')
```

assigns `'('` to answer and checks if it is non-zero (which it is) -- so the first branch is always executed.

You need:

```
if (answer == '(')
```

instead (similarly for the other).

you also need a closing `}` before the `while`